# Checking two cells in a column before copying information from a different cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm trying to check if two pieces of information match what i need in a column before copying a different cell.

The logical process, Check if information in first and second row of a column match information in the destination.
If they are correct, then go down a different column and check for a row containing a third piece of information.

Next copy the intersection point between the column with the two pieces of information and the row with the third piece of information.

Here is my example formula:

```
=IFERROR(
    IF(AND(COUNTIF(D2:G2, D12:G12)>0, COUNTIF(D3:G3, C14:C17)>0), INDEX(D4:G9, MATCH(D13:G13, C4:C9, 0), MATCH(C14:C17, D3:G3, 0)), "No Match"),
    "No Match")
```

And a photo of how it relates to the cells
[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqmSW.png)

So you would expect it to copy the number 1 from cell D4 to cell D14 where RR and HH are in the top column and EDD in the row to the left. I had this working with a simpler example where it only checked one column and row.

The formula for it is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D4:G9, MATCH(N2:Q2, C4:C9, 0), MATCH(M3:M6, D3:G3, 0)), "No Match")
```

[Simpler version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmHnG.png)

When I try for two elements it doesn't seem to work as well.

Comment: You can't use a multi-cell range as the look up value in a MATCH formula.